# When send individual parameter, action result cannot be hit. when send object, it gets hit

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, httprequest, asp.net-web-api2

I have one application consist of ASP.Net WebAPI 2 and Web project for which angularJS is used. The Problem is when i call API with parameters, it does not hit. and when send object, it gets hit.

**anjularJS Code:**

**with parameters**

```
$http({
    cache: false
        , method: 'POST'
        , url: 'http://localhost:51341/api/User/UpdateUser'
        , data: { userId: $scope.UsersId, fullName: $scope.name }
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

***Webapi Code***

```
[HttpPost]
public ApiResponse UpdateUser(int userId, string fullName)
{
    return this.Response(true, MessageTypes.Success, "User has been saved successfully.");
}
```

**with object**

```
var model = { userId: $scope.UsersId, fullName: $scope.name };
$http({
    cache: false
        , method: 'POST'
        , url: 'http://localhost:51341/api/User/UpdateUser'
        , data: model
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
});
```

**webapi code**

```
[HttpPost]
public ApiResponse UpdateUser(User model)
{
    return this.Response(true, MessageTypes.Success, "User has been saved successfully.");
}
```

**User class**

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

when call made with parameters, api DOES NOT get hit. but When call made with Object, api GETS hit.

What I missed when call made with parameters ? Help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [WebApi docs](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api):

> At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So
>   this will not work:
>
> ```
> // Caution: Will not work!    
> public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
> ```

For other info I suggest to read:

https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/08/22/web-api-2-exploring-parameter-binding/
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629106/3316654