# 415 error Web Api POST from Angular

Tags: angularjs, post, asp.net-web-api

Spent hours battling simple POST request to a Web API controller.

```html
Here's the response header from Postman:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Cache-Control → no-cache
Content-Length → 2153
Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8
Date → Wed, 04 Nov 2015 23:26:14 GMT
Expires → -1
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version → 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By → ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles → =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcSnVsaWFcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFZpc3VhbCBTdHVkaW8gMjAxM1xQcm9qZWN0c1xUd2lsZHlcQVBJXGFwaVxUZXN0XHRlc3Rc?=
```

I tried both of these POST methods with no success:

1. ```js
           [Route("api/{Test}/test")]
           [HttpPost]
           public void PostByProducts(Test t)
           {
               Console.Write(t.Name);
           }
   ```
2. Update: below is replaced with the code that finally worked. Note, I added Name="PostData" which is the name of the Controller. Otherwise, was getting "null reference" error. "Data data" itself is a class in the Models.

```js
    [ResponseType(typeof(Data))]
    [Route("api/{Test}/testpost/", Name="PostData")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostData(Data data)
    {
        int rValue = 0;
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        else
        {
            if (data != null)
            {
                rValue = repo.PostTestMe(data);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("PostData", rValue, data);
    }
```

On #1 my class "Test" always comes in as null, regardless of the request content-type. I tried them all in Postman, including json. Reading some of the SO answers I did add an empty constructor to the model class ("Test")

On #2 (Old:I get null value when posted from angular) Works from angular now too with the updated code posted here. Works when I post from Postman.

I am at my wits end. All I want to do is to post a simple form from Angular.

Update: Now it works in Postman. I get a non-null value into the function, and get this response in Postman:

```html
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Cache-Control → no-cache
Content-Length → 1308
Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8
Date → Thu, 05 Nov 2015 03:15:26 GMT
Expires → -1
Pragma → no-cache
Server → Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version → 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By → ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles → =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcSnVsaWFcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFZpc3VhbCBTdHVkaW8gMjAxM1xQcm9qZWN0c1xUd2lsZHlcQVBJXGFwaVx0ZXN0cG9zdA==?=
```

Here's what I send in Postman:
[image]

Angular code: (formdata is straight from the html form, referenced with form.Field1, form.Field2, etc corresponding to the C# model class)

```js
        factory.postForm = function(formdata) {
          return $http({
            url: 'http://domain.com/api/test/testpost',
            data: JSON.stringify(formdata),
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
          }).success(function(response) {
            console.log('posted ' + formdata)
          });
        }
```

(Old: Still getting null into the API post function.) Everything works fine.

Final update:

In all fairness, when I uploaded my source code to the live server which lives on a shared host, and API is hosted under the same domain, just a different project, everything worked fine, and I got 201 Created OK response.

So, it was a CORS issue, I suppose, which is interesting, because everything works fine on local host for GET requests, but POST gave me hard times.

BTW, I ended up not using [FromBody] - it worked without it.

Update: Ended up adding Name to the route. Everything works.

Comment: remove charset=utf-8 from this line Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: tried with and without charset. Same result. null value in API.

Comment: please mention your calling header

Comment: Can you post your angularjs code?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the similar problem earlier and in my case adding [FromBody] before class parameter had solved the problem.

In your case the test method needs to be something like below.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult PostTest([FromBody]Test test)
{
}
```

The detailed description for FromUri and FromBody can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625303/why-we-have-to-specify-frombody-and-fromuri-in-asp-net-web-api).

Comment: Still getting null if posting from angular. Post from Postman works fine.

Comment: I guess somehow Postman avoids the whole CORS thing; maybe it does not run under any web server, even simulated, or maybe it injects itself into the localhost where api runs.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent hours looking around here in stackoverflow and in google for a solution and here is what I did to solve that

When using `HttpClientModule` in Angular you do not need to call `JSON.stringify(formdata)` since the data parameter is stringify as needed

```
@Injectable()
export class ParkingService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(parking: Parking) {
    const requestUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'parking' ;
    const headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();

    headerOptions.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    //In this line is my issue
    return this.http.post(requestUrl, JSON.stringify(parking), {headers: headerOptions}) ; 
  }
}
```

I changed that line to this and it worked (given that it works from postman)

```
return this.http.post(requestUrl, parking, {headers: headerOptions}) ;
```

If your angular client is accesing a web api in a differente port/machine you need to enable CORS in that API. For .Net Core here are some good answers [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi) if its some other programing language look it up in the same way