# Angular 4 with ASP.NET Core 2.0 is giving back 401 error on JWT (CORS)

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, cors

I´ve written front-end application in Angular 4. This front-end is trying to make a request to endpoints which required authorization token. I am using JWT token with ASP.NET Core 2.0. Because both are running on different ports, i have to set **CORS**.

So request with added **Authorization** header returns response from server with `401 Error code.` I tried to use many solution from these threads:

1. [Setting cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi) *there is also idea with custom CorsMiddleware,

   which I Tried, but still receiving 401.*
2. [Similiar solution to custom    Cors middleware](https://www.developerhandbook.com/c-sharp/create-restful-api-authentication-using-web-api-jwt/)
3. [Custom cors middleware](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-with-angular-5-http-client-and-asp-net-core-web-api/) *This wasn´t even working*

, which at first glance appear to be solving a similar problem. However, I am not able to get right response from server. Method **without** attribute `[Authorize]` are working correctly (*Methods which don´t need Bearer token*) Could be error somewhere else? (Token are indeed valid, tested from POSTMAN). **Have anybody idea, what's could be a problem?**

---

#### This is how I set CORS

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
    });
}
```

#### Apply Cors before Mvc

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
IHostingEnvironment env, UnitOfWork identityCustomDbContext)
{

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseMvc();

}
```

#### Angular token interceptor

```
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private injector: Injector, private _router: Router){}

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{
        const auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
        let token = auth.getToken();
        if(token){
                const authReq = req.clone({headers:req.headers.set('Authorization', token).set('Content-Type','application/json')})
                return next.handle(authReq);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Requests headers

---

**OPTIONS request**

status code: 204 No Content

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:57498/api/users
Host: localhost:57498
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
```

**OPTIONS response**

```
Server: Kestrel
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcQ29uZmVlLWJhY2tlbmRcQ29uZmVlLXdlYkFwaVxDb25mZWUtd2ViQXBpXGFwaVx1c2Vycw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

**GET request**

status code: 401 Unauthorized

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:4200/admin/conferences
Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJsdUBzLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6ImJmMDk3ZmYwLTRjMGUtNGZkMC04YTM1LTQ4MzZlY2U2OGE0OSIsImh0dHA6Ly9zY2hlbWFzLnhtbHNvYXAub3JnL3dzLzIwMDUvMDUvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL25hbWVpZGVudGlmaWVyIjoiYmMzZWQxMzQtMTAyNS00OWVjLTk1YWYtZDk0ODMxNWVmYzI0IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9yb2xlIjoiQWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvciIsImV4cCI6MTUyMDUzNzQ3MCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1NzQ5OC8iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjU3NDk4LyJ9.rUwoq_olnVg7lOvtX1AIpB1JDDwBi9ra3FhBLaSSLuQ
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
```

**GET response**

```
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcQ29uZmVlLWJhY2tlbmRcQ29uZmVlLXdlYkFwaVxDb25mZWUtd2ViQXBpXGFwaVx1c2Vycw==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 0
```

---

#### According to link 2 and 3 above, I tried to implement custom CORS middleware

```
public class CorsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CorsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Date, X-Api-Version, X-File-Name");
        httpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        return _next(httpContext);
    }
}
public static class CorsMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseCorsMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<CorsMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
IHostingEnvironment env, UnitOfWork identityCustomDbContext)
{
app.UseCorseMiddleware();
app.UseMvc();
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
}
```

The result was same. I have recieved 401 from server.

Comment: Here is my guess: you are passing a token to the service, but you are not including the word *bearer* before the token, so the service has no clue what to do with it. Maybe?

Comment: @R.Richards oh my lord, you are indeed right! How could I missed this crucial part?! Thank you so much, sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer.

You are passing a token to the service, but you are not including the word *bearer* before the token string, so the service has no clue what to do with it, thus the 401 Unauthorized.

Easy enough to miss. Postman handles this for you, so you may not think about it with Angular.