# How to fix "The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time" error

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I've already enabled CORS on the project in C# .net Core

In `startup.cs` I've added lines

```
...
services.AddCors();
...
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials());
```

But when I try to use API in another `Blazor` project I see in logs in my API project on Host this error

> The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin
>   and credentials at the same time. Configure the policy by listing
>   individual origins if credentials needs to be supported

My code in `Blazor`

```
using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient()) {
  http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Token");
   var response = await http.GetStringAsync("https://example.com?prm=2");
   Console.WriteLine(response);
   dynamicContent = response;
}
```

Before I enable Cors I see another error in the browser console

What can I change for solving it?

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  You can't specify `*` for the origin when using credentials.  Set the origin to your server's actual domain name.  Also, these headers must be set *by the server*, not in your client headers.

Comment: @Amy And what the solution?

Comment: I already told you the solution, as does the error message.  Again, "Set the origin to your server's actual domain name."

Comment: @Amy instead of "*" I have to put "https://example.com"?

Comment: Instead of “*” please put “https://example.com” (including protocol) as suggested by Amy.. The limitation is only 1 external domain can be specified..

Comment: @bestinamir I did it, but the problem is not solved

Comment: Again, this needs to be set **on the server**, not in your client.

Comment: May be try going with this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44379971/10634638

Comment: @daniherrera Yes, You are right. It's probably a host's problem because now I've tried to call another API server and it's work well. Maybe I need to config nginx

Comment: @daniherrera @amy I've solved it  just drop `http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` and in row
   `var response = await Http.GetStringAsync("https://example.com?prm=2");` change `Http` to `http`

Comment: You can follow this link, it's work for me: https://mykkon.work/how-to-setup-any-origin/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should have provided the rest of your code...
Is this a Blazor client application or Razor Components application (formally known as Server-Side Blazor) ?
I guess this is a Blazor client application, right ?
Why do you instantiate an HttpClient ? You should use DI (Perhaps Constructor Injection) instead, injecting an HttpClient instance provided by Blazor itself.

The problem is probably server side, though it surfaces as a client one...
Try the following:

Get `https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors/`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
    });
     .....
}
```

And this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)    
{
      app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
}
```

Note, once again: CORS needs to be enabled on the **server side**, not in blazor. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors for details on how to enable CORS in ASP.NET Core.

Blazor:

```
 @page "/<template>"
 @inject HttpClient Http


@functions {

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        var response= await Http.GetJsonAsync<string>    
                      ("https://example.com?prm=2");

    }

}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Credentials cannot be used with any origin.  See the comments on the question.

Comment: On the server, I have .net Core API project - and now I develop Blazor client project. In my question is shown that I add and use Cors. It's not help me

Answer (score 114):

I had the same issue and I removed `AllowCredentials()` that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Yes, this was applicable for me when upgrading from Asp.Net Core 2.1 to Asp.Net Core 3.1

Comment: Thanks, one bug less while upgrading to Net Core 3.1 from Net Core 2.2 :)

Comment: Thanks. That was the issue for me also!

Answer (score 65):

It's little bit late, but I hope it could be helpful for someone.

If you want `AllowCredentials()` and `AllowAnyOrigin()` together just use `SetIsOriginAllowed(Func<string,bool> predicate)`

[doc about IsOriginAllowed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors.infrastructure.corspolicy.isoriginallowed?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Cors_Infrastructure_CorsPolicy_IsOriginAllowed)

```
        services
            .AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    );

                options.AddPolicy("signalr",
                    builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()

                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed(hostName => true));
            });
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer, allows AnyOrigin and Credentials at the same time.

Comment: This is very dangerous if the server is publicly accessible, see https://ejj.io/misconfigured-cors/

Comment: Some APIs are designed to be consumed from customers sites like integrations. This is the correct answer as long as you know what you are doing and apply it only to the correct controllers etc.

Answer (score 50):

I also faced same issue, and I found solution here:

[Setup Any Origin And Any Credentials](https://mykkon.work/how-to-setup-any-origin/)

Change your CORS setup in startup.cs file like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => 
            builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
    });
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: I had to add "app.UseCors" under Configure in Startup.cs to get this to work

Comment: Thanks Kurniawan Prasetyo. Your solution has worked for me! :)

Comment: OMG, I love you I have been searching for something like this last 2 days!

Answer (score 21):

Step 1
Install nuGet package :
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors

Step 2
add

```
services.AddCors();
```

in startup.cs under ConfigureServices

Step 3
add

```
    app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                .AllowCredentials());
```

in startup.cs under Configure

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use both `AllowAnyOrigin()` and `AllowCredentials()` at the sametime
so change your code to:

```
...
services.AddCors();
...
app.UseCors(builder => builder
    .WithOrigins("https://example.com")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowCredentials());
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the problem was solved by removing **slash**( **/** ) from the ending of URL, because I always copy and paste urls from chrome browser and it has the **/** at the end :

```
  .WithOrigins("https://localhost:60576/")  // not working
```

but

```
  .WithOrigins("https://localhost:60576")  // working  !!!
```