# ASP.NET WebAPI2 and AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using firefox to perform a connection between an AngularJS/HTML client page and a controller on the ASP.NET WebAPI.

The issue is that I keep getting the "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:44377/project/all. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)." unless I enable the CORS firefox extension.

Even with that enabled, my page doesn't seem to be grabbing the required data; but the errors are gone.

[EnableCors(origins: "https://localhost:PortNumberHereWithoutTheForwardSlah", headers: "*", methods: "*")] above my Controller:ApiController and used the config.EnableCors(); in the WebApi.Config in App_Start.

Note: the method that uses [HttpGet] does work when I try to use it in my browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "The CORS protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard (any) origin and credentials at the same time" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53675850/how-to-fix-the-cors-protocol-does-not-allow-specifying-a-wildcard-any-origin)

Comment: No, I'm on ASP.net MVC

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079214/how-to-enable-cross-origin-requests-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

</system.webServer> Thanks, but I found inserting this between /handlers and /system.webServer in Web.config to be more flexible from another post.

Comment: </handlers> <httpProtocol> <customHeaders> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" /> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" /> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" /> </customHeaders> </httpProtocol> </system.webServer> Thanks, but I found inserting this between /handlers and /system.webServer in Web.config to be more flexible from another post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).