# How to debug "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

My API Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Loan>> Get()
{
    return _context.Loans;
}
```

**Loan.cs**

```
public class Loan
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerName { get; set; }
    public decimal RepaymentAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal FundingAmount { get; set; }
}
```

**Loan.ts**

```
export class Loan {
    constructor(
        public Id : number,
        public BorrowerName : string,
        public RepaymentAmount : number,
        public FundingAmount : number
    ) { }
}
```

**loans.component.ts**

I can see that the `http` get is indeed calling my API and it is returning the expected data.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Loan } from '../loan';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loans',
  templateUrl: './loans.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loans.component.css']
})
export class LoansComponent implements OnInit {

  loans: Loan[];

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {

    this.getLoans().subscribe((loans) => {
      this.loans = loans;
      console.log(loans);
    })
  }

  getLoans() {
    return <Observable<Loan[]>> this.http.get('http://localhost:1113/api/loans');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I am seeing this error in the console:

[image]

How can I get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console says the request is blocked due to CORS. You need to add CORS support to the server: https://enable-cors.org/server.html.

Read more about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors.

Comment: Thanks Kristoffer, I managed to find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi) thanks to your comment