# How do I config the API in ASP.NET Core for access the http request?

Tags: angular, sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, ionic3

I want to send the data to back-end for creating the details about customers using http post method with API URL. But it refused to connect the back-end. because it need some permission for access the post method. please give some guide line and resolve this error.

i already do some changes in app.setting  for Allow-permission-* in back-end side. but nothing happend.

```
    //This is my ts code

    this.http.post('http://localhost:2401/api/CustomerAPI', 
    jstring).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  });
}
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:2401/api/CustomerAPI' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Then it also show Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: could you CustomerAPI post code

Comment: var jstring = JSON.stringify({
        CodeId: this.Code, customerNameId: this.CustomerName,
        ProjectnameId: this.Projectname, SortcodeId: this.Sortcode, contactId: this.contact,
        AddressId: this.Address, Address2Id: this.Address2, CountryId: this.Country, PostalcodeId: this.Postalcode,
        PhoneId: this.Phone, FaxId: this.Fax, CheckeboxId: this.Checkebox, DescriptionId: this.Description

Comment: I want to do some access permission in my Back-end at "appsettings.json"

Answer (score 0):

You are having CORS issue, Read this [CORS in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2) 
Also, a solution is this [.NET CORS solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: I already red that i'm new to .net so i can't understand. What they are explained there???? can u please help me by any other way?

Comment: you need to configure your server to allow headers, methods, origins so your client-side app (ionic App) can send requests to your server and get a response. Click on this link and do exactly what they listed out there [Solution] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844400/6800815)

Comment: wow thanks a lot for your reference.... That was clearly explained there.

Comment: how do i do that? because i'm new to here!

Comment: find more information [here] (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)