# Axios could not fetch data from asp.net core web service

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, axios, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to fetch data from web service in asp.net core but I keep getting error message instead, though, I had tried the same URL in Postman and also in web browser, and it worked just fine; notice that I've disabled **SSL** in asp.net core to make it work with **HTTP** I even provided some configurations like **Content-Type**, but I still get the same error.

in **Vue.js**

```
    fetch(e) {

       e.preventDefault();

       const axiosConfiguration = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                }
            }


  axios.get('http://localhost:62750/api/users/',axiosConfiguration ).then( response => {
                     alert(JSON.stringify(response))
                 }).catch(e => {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(e))
                 })

            }
```

in **C# Asp.net Core**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SchoolContext _context;

        public UsersController(SchoolContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Users>>> GetUsers()
        {
            return await _context.Users.ToListAsync();
        }

    }
```

Error I get

> {"message":"Network Error","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Network
>   Error\n    at createError
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n
>   at XMLHttpRequest.handleError
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:81:14)","config":{"url":"http://localhost:62750/api/users","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   text/plain,
>   */*"},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1}}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Shivam Sood nope I don't have to write the link as you've have written it, it's the default link unless I provide metadata with annotation like `[HttpGet("getusers")]` or `[Route("getusers")]` , plus I've already told you it works just fine in Postman and Web browser

Comment: Is `CORS` enabled?

Comment: @Shivam Sood what's that?? and on which side should I enable `CORS`? on front-end or back-end?

Comment: `CORS` is `Cross Origin Resource Sharing` which basically means when you are making request to different PORT it is blocked by default, so you need to  enable it in order to make request to `localhost:62750` from different PORT. you need to enable it in your .net api

Comment: @ShivamSood you were right, I've configured `CORS` to allow any website to work with api written in Asp.net core, thanks a lot, you are awesome. **thumbs up**

Comment: I wrote it as an answer so that other's can find the solution, if you feel like it you can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure `CORS` on your `.net core API`.
CORS is `Cross Origin Resource Sharing` which basically means when you are making request to different PORT it is blocked by default, so you need to enable it in order to make request to localhost:62750 from different PORT.

Here's one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi) on how you can do it.