# Angular 11 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-web-api

I Have `dotnet core 5` application and `Angular app`  that in `local host` All `Http methods` working well but on the web host `HttpGet, HttpPost Methods`  working correctly and `HttpPut, DELETE` thrown Exception:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '---' from origin '---' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

that config `Cors` like bellow:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAdminApiCors(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                    builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                    builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                });
        });

        return services;
    }
```

in `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAdminApiCors();

        services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }

[Authorize]
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<CompanyViewModel>>> Get([FromQuery] CompanyQuery companyQuery)
    {
        return Ok(await _mediator.Send(companyQuery));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Create([FromBody] CreateCompanyCommand command)
    {
        var productId = await _mediator.Send(command);

        return Ok(productId);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody] UpdateCompanyCommand command)
    {
        await _mediator.Send(command);

        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    [ProducesDefaultResponseType]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        await _mediator.Send(new DeleteCompanyCommand { Id = id });

        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

in many posts told change `web.config` file and remove `WebDAV IIS Module` that i follow them but my problam not solved
[cors put error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521499/cors-support-for-put-and-delete-with-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Could you please have a try with add the [EnableCors] on each action instead of add it on controller.

Comment: And since the "Get" and "Post" method work fine, so please check if the `ProducesResponseType` and `ProducesDefaultResponseType` annotations could affect the two methods("put" and "delete" method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after 5 days I find my problem reason, it need to remove Web in `Web.config` file

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules> 
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/> 
  </modules>  
</system.webServer>
```

and some changes applied in hosted server by hosting provider company supporter

Answer (score 1):

This works for my project :

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder =>
            builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
    });
```

Comment: @MohsenSaleh Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61428395/in-net-core-2-1-web-api-for-put-and-delete-only-why-no-access-control-allow-o) ?

Comment: yes i test it may related to `iis config`

Answer (score 0):

potentially there are an exception happened in your code and the server send you this misleading response you can detect the exception by go to the hosted application and go the `web.config` file and enable log by set it `true` and initiate another request and go the log file already generated and debug the issue.

Comment: hi, no I trace it by empty `post action` `controller` and error occurs, this erorr may related to `iis config`

Comment: hi, i mean it must be an error happened in one of the action methods ( put or delete ) you can check them