# Call to my rest service from Angular app hosted in Asp.net core web server blocked by CORS policy

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, cors, cross-domain-policy

I have a Angular App that is hosted in Asp.net core web server, though this Angular app i am calling another Rest api service for getting some data but my call to external Rest Service api is blocked by CORS policy.

The Error i am getting in browser is -

[image]

and my Asp.net server application **Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace WebclientServer
{
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit 
    https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
          options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
              builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader());
        });
        services.AddMvc();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request 
    pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //if (env.IsDevelopment())
        //{
        //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //}

        //app.UseRouting();

        //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        //{
        //    endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
        //    {
        //        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        //    });
        //});

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            await next();
            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
               !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
               !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
                await next();
            }
        });
        //app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
    }
  }
}
```

I have read about how to solve this error on internet from this link [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi) but no sucess in my case. Please dont mind i am new to web development stuff, and on CORS policy error i am already stuck for days. Please help on how can i solve this error. Also do i have to enable CORS on my External Rest api service. 
Thanks!

Comment: use jsonp: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584/240564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is a server side "*problem*", not client. So, I guess, you should not try to fix it on your client (i.e., Angular even if it is hosted on X server-type). That's why, I think, your ASP.net fix is not working. Trying to fix CORS on client-side, although sometimes possible, most times leads to errors or just the server ignoring/blocking the requests.

The **simpliest approach** is to **configure CORS** on your server side. You've specified that you are accessing an **External REST API**. Thus, there is where you have to dig in, and forget client fixes.

Comment: yes i have figured this out, and the problem was at External Rest API server side, I have enabled the CORS on that and now its working.