# Web Api Still Getting Cors Errors After Installing Microsoft.AspNet.Cors And Enabling Cors On Controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-ajax, webapi

I am buildind a Web Api app locally and I am calling the methods using simple jQuery ajax method calls. As per the title I have installed the Microsoft.AspNet.Cors package via nuget and enabled cors in my WebApiConfig.cs and on my controller like this

[EnableCors(origins: "https://localhost:44397", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "X-My-Header")]

I have even tried this

[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*", exposedHeaders: "*")]

but when I make the call via ajax I still get the error - Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44397/api/Default/PostRegisterUser' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Why is this happening and how do I resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: Hi I've gone through all the suggestions in the link above but still it doesn't work.