# Angular js front end and .net backend getting CORS error Response to preflight request. Also no page is getting after login

Tags: .net, angularjs, azure, iis, azure-ad-b2c

He have deployed two apps

- Frontend: Angular.js (UI)
- Backend: .Net framework (API)

We executed from azure pipeline and deployed to IIS. No error application deployed. We have linked in api in config.js file

```
test_app = {
  environment: "prod",
  apiUrls: {
    mr: "https://new-mr-api.xxx.com/api",
    sites: "https://sitesapi.xxx.com/api",
  },
  azureAD: {
    clientId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    loginAuthorityPolicyName: "B2C_1A_MR_SignUp_SignIn_AAD",
    passwordResetPolicyName: "B2C_1A_MR_PasswordReset",
    tenantName: "cappartners",
    appIds: {
      mr: "mr-test",
      sites: "apis",
    },
  },
  powerBI: {
    workspaceId: "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    dockOrderStatusId: "7rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr",
  },
  applicationInsights: {
    instrumentationKey: "1111111111111111111111111111111",
    roleName: "Browser",
    roleInstance: "PROD",
  },
  googleMapsApiKey: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
};
```

Here in mr we provided API url. Also added b2c url for login
So when we hit the UI url http://new-mr.xxx.com then we are getting login microsoft azure b2c login page. After login nothing is displaying. When we check in developer/inspect page console we are getting **CORS blocked error**[image]

we have added CORS in api **webapiconfig.js** like

```
using System.Web.Http.Cors
...........
so on...

string origins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors:origins"];
string headers = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors:headers"];
string methods = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cors:methods"];
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(origins, headers, methods, "API-Build-Number");
config.EnableCors(cors);
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
.............. so on....
```

Also added cors in Web.config

```
<add key="cors:origins" value="*" />
<!--<add key="cors:headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authentication" />
<add key="cors:methods" value="GET, POST PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS" />-->
<add key="cors:headers" value="*" />
<add key="cors:methods" value="*" />
```

Please help in loading the page and resolving the error. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried answers from here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi

Comment: As per above file webapiconfig.js i guess we have enabled CORS.

Comment: On IIS, the best defense is to configure CORS module on IIS, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module which rules out most preflight errors.

Answer (score 0):

Also try  configure the CORS in your ConfigureServices method on your Startup.cs in your .net API

```
Public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add service and create Policy with options
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials() );
    });
```

and use `app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");` in *configure services* method.

Also make sure to select correct token type from below to access you api,
[image]

Also check if you need to adjust the packages > [microsoft identity web issues(github.com)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/581)

Answer (score 0):

This type of error is very common please check your controller name

***For example:***

```
[HttpPatch]
[Route("UserProfileUpdate")]
public async Task<ActionResult<MyHtApiResponse>> UserProfileUpdate(AdminVM adminVM)
```

In this example, The Route name and controller name are same, sometime it also give this type of error