# CORS error calling ASP.NET Core 5 Web Application for Telerik Reporting

Tags: .net-core, cors, telerik-reporting

Following the Telerik walkthrough [here](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/using-reports-in-applications/host-the-report-engine-remotely/telerik-reporting-rest-services/asp.net-core-web-api-implementation/host-reports-service-in-.net-5) to create a Telerik Report host.

In the .NET CORE 5 project I enable CORS as follows:

In Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // Configure dependencies for ReportsController.
        services.TryAddSingleton<IReportServiceConfiguration>(sp =>
        new ReportServiceConfiguration
        {
            //ReportingEngineConfiguration = ConfigurationHelper.ResolveConfiguration(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>()),
            ReportingEngineConfiguration = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>(),
            HostAppId = "Net5RestServiceWithCors",
            Storage = new FileStorage(),
            ReportSourceResolver = new UriReportSourceResolver(
                System.IO.Path.Combine(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootPath, "Reports"))
        });

        services.AddCors(corsOption => corsOption.AddPolicy(
          "ReportingRestPolicy",
          corsBuilder =>
          {
              corsBuilder.WithOrigins("*")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
              //corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin()
              //  .AllowAnyMethod()
              //  .AllowAnyHeader();
          }
        ));

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("ReportingRestPolicy");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        

    }
```

The launchSettings.cs are as follows:

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:65271",
      "sslPort": 44398
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MyReportServer": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To test I run the project and change the URL to https://localhost:44398/api/reports/version and I receive the correct response "16.1.22.511".

Then I open a new web browser and navigate to to https://localhost:44398/api/reports/version  and get the same valid response.

In my front end project I set the report url as:

```
var reporturi = "https://localhost:44398/api/reports"
```

When the report viewer begins the report retrieval process it first calls the report version endpoint and I receive a CORS error in the report viewer.

**Cannot access the Reporting REST service. (serviceUrl = 'https://localhost:44398/api/reports'). Make sure the service address is correct and enable CORS if needed. (https://enable-cors.org)**

Running Chrome I inspect the F12 Network tab I see a Name of "version" and a Status of "CORS error".

Inspecting the Headers:

```
General
    Request URL: https://localhost:44398/api/reports/version
    Request Method: GET
    Status Code: 200 
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Response Headers
    access-control-allow-origin: *
    content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    date: Mon, 30 May 2022 14:10:10 GMT
    server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
    x-powered-by: ASP.NET

Request Headers
    :authority: localhost:44398
    :method: GET
    :path: /api/reports/version
    :scheme: https
    accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    origin: http://localhost:1202
    referer: http://localhost:1202/
    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"
    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
    sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    sec-fetch-mode: cors
    sec-fetch-site: cross-site
    user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36
```

Based on this it appears that the endpoint is valid and the server's access-control-allow-origin is allowing all.

I modified the server to specifically allow http://localhost:1202 as well with the same result.

```
              corsBuilder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:1202")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
```

I also tried the AlowAnyOrigin method:

```
              corsBuilder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader();
```

I am enabling CORS in Startup.cs *Configue* between *app.UseRouting();* and *app.UseEndpoints()* as is recommended.

The Status Code is 200 for the request which is Success and this may be normal even if a CORS error occurs, I'm not sure.

What can I try to resolve this CORS error?

Answer (score 0):

From [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

I needed to add AllowCredentials().

In working through this I made several adjustments to my original code. I moved all CORS statements to the top of the statup.cs methods and I changed the policy-based CORS setup to the simpler non-policy syntax, but what got it to work was the addition of AllowCredentials().

Note to use ***AllowCredentials()*** you cannot also use ***AllAnyOrigin()***, you must instead use ***WithOrigins()*** and specify each.

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        // Configure dependencies for ReportsController.
        services.TryAddSingleton<IReportServiceConfiguration>(sp =>
        new ReportServiceConfiguration
        {
            ReportingEngineConfiguration = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>(),
            HostAppId = "Net5RestServiceWithCors",
            Storage = new FileStorage(),
            ReportSourceResolver = new UriReportSourceResolver(
                System.IO.Path.Combine(sp.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>().ContentRootPath, "Reports"))
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseCors(
               options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:1202").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()
           );

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });

        

    }
```

Honestly I don't know why this needs to be so difficult, just saying.