# Getting error - localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 502 - GraphQL run on Visual Studio 2022 - Hotchocolate

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-6.0, hotchocolate

I am trying to execute a simple default Graphql app on Visual studio 2022 on .net 6 and 7.
When the app is executed from visual studio I get the error "localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 502". I'm using HotChololate.aspnetcore (13.5.1)

App URL "http://localhost:64264/graphql"

Note: I have graphql app developed on .net 6 and later when I installed .net 7 and started to create new apps on .net 6 or .net 7. The app is not loading and throwing the error.

**Below is the Query.cs page**

```
namespace GraphQL_Sample.Schema.Queries
{
    public class Query
    {
        public string Welcome()
        {
            return "Simple GraphQL App";
        }
    }
}
```

**Below is the Program.cs**

```
using GraphQL_Sample.Schema.Queries;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
{

    builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer()
        .AddQueryType<Query>();
}

var app = builder.Build();
{

    app.MapGraphQL();

    app.Run();
}
```

**Below is the content for appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Below is the content of launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64264",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "GraphQL_Sample": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5208",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Below is the error page.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xyPd.png)

I tried using the solution from below link to use AddCors() and UseCors(). But still didn't work.

[How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: Same here, except using HotChocolate v13.8.1

Comment: I tried two things. 
1. Down graded graphql version. 
   OR
2. Implemented below code in program.cs  

 app.MapGraphQL()
         .WithOptions(new GraphQLServerOptions()
         {
             Tool = { ServeMode = GraphQLToolServeMode.Embedded }
         });