# I want to connect react app to swagger local API but I get cors error, how can I solve it?

Tags: c#, reactjs, cors, swagger

This is my Swagger API I built in C# Visual Studio 2022:

[image: swager api]

and this is my simply react code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function FetchData() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://localhost:7119/api/Items/Items');
      setData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    }
  };

  
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(item => (
        <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default FetchData;
```

and this is the error I got:

[image: error message]

I want to get info from the API (in my local computer) that I built in C# (VS2022)
to a react app, I try to understands how to cancel the cors
in the swagger documentation but I didn't find a solution.

https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/cors/

Comment: If your API is .NET Core, [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: Give [this](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/all-you-need-to-know-cors-errors) a read to get an understanding about cors and how to fix it.

Comment: Swagger is not the cause of the CORS issue. It is only a playground that interfaces directly with your API, which is where the issue is. You need to fix any CORS issues in the backend API.