# ASP.NET Core MVC and Web API on the same IIS server

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two applications:

1. ASP.NET Core MVC web app
2. ASP.NET Core Web API

When I run the applications on my computer, everything works and the MVC app can make get/post http requests to my API.

When I publish to the server, my **LOCAL** MVC app still can make the get/post http requests.

But when the ASP.NET Core MVC app is published to the server, it can make just `Get` requests, but not `Post` requests anymore.

Both application are on the same server, under the same domain. Both use http and not https.

Does someone know if I'm missing something?

I tried a lot of things: learnt about CORS origin, transfer to http or https. Change the url to post...

Comment: with postMan every ting work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)

Comment: Some extra information would be good to understand your problem. 
Could you share the code that makes the actual GET or POST request, and the actual error message you are getting?

Comment: It does look like it's a cross-origin request related issue, you can try to refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0) to see if these policy settings are useful, as already mentioned it would help if you could provide a minimal code example that reproduces the issue solve.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of CORS where the browser does prevent the call of your rest apis when anybody tries it from postman or other URLs. Basically what you can do is create CORS policy and allow them as per your requirement.

Here is how you can do this in your program.cs or startup.cs file

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
      options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                  policy  =>
                  {
                      policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                          "http://www.contoso.com");
                  });
 });
```

You can find more information about this at following links

https://www.bytehide.com/blog/cors-aspnet-core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0

https://medium.com/@M-B-A-R-K/what-is-cors-in-asp-net-core-85f4903c9d43

Answer (score 0):

i found my problem.

1. i'm using a http request under the same origin, so its not about cors.
2. my program was looking for configuration from the appsettings.production file and not from appsettings.json file. and the database connection string wasn't right.
   thanks for everyone.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the question and providing the solution. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community member in future in similar kind of issues.