# How to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers in a Axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, http, http-headers

I'm developing a **Microservices** that contains a **.Asp.Net Backend** and a **React.tsx** frontend. The **Backend** seems to workout properly because I can access data from Navigator:

[image]

But when I tried to fetch it from the **Frontend** with **Axios** library, navigator returns

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is how I settled the **CORS** config in `Program.cs`

```
    builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod();
                });
            });

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

And this is the Typescript Component that request the **API**:

```
 const Subjects = async ({}) => {
        try {
        const { data, status} =  await axios.get<GetSubjectResponse>(url,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
              }
            );
        console.log("status is:", status)

        return data
        } catch (error) {
            if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
            console.log('error message: ', error.message);
            return error.message;
            } else {
            console.log('unexpected error: ', error);
            return 'An unexpected error occurred';
            }
        }
```

And Navigator, of course, return:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://5000-app.ws-us107.gitpod.io/api/Subject/Get/GetAll' from origin 'https://3000-app.ws-us107.gitpod.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: It's backend's fault. You have to set these headers on the backend

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable CORS in ASP.net Core WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379560/how-to-enable-cors-in-asp-net-core-webapi)