# ASP.NET MVC - Web Api - Model binding with FromUriAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

All my requestModels are passed via Uri.

Is there any chance to use [FromUriAttribute] implicitly instead of applying them to each request model?

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Test([FromUri]MyClass requestModel)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: The method in your example is a GET so isn't it implicit that the model will come from the URI anyway?

Comment: only in case the model is simple type (int, double, string etc.)

Comment: looking at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24629106/1241562 it looks like `[FromUri]` is implicit when the method is `GET` (and `[FromBody]` when `POST`).

Comment: No, it isn't the case. See the answer of this topic stackoverflow.com/a/24629106/1241562

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work. Because it tries to bind model from [body], but there is nothing in it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just set up some test examples and it didn't work. Bill's answer below does what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using self hosting, then you can add a parameter binding rule to the WebApiConfig.Register class

```
config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0,typeof(MyClass),x=>x.BindWithAttribute(new FromUriAttribute()));
```

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

---edited
All parts of the web api 2 framework are extendable with some exceptions. In this case it is possible to modify the default behavior of how the web api 2 attempts to bind complex type parameters for all get requests by overriding the behavior of the DefaultActionValueProvider and replacing the default implementation with a custom one. There is a good example of how this may be accomplished at the following link.

http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/

Specifically this is a two step process:

derive a new class the extends the DefaultValueProvider

replace the existing implementation in the services collection

From the URI above this is done in the section "Defaulting to [FromUri] for GET and HEAD requests"

1-Extending the implementation

```
public class CustomActionValueBinder : DefaultActionValueBinder
{
protected override HttpParameterBinding GetParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor parameter)
{
    return parameter.ActionDescriptor.SupportedHttpMethods.Contains(HttpMethod.Get) || parameter.ActionDescriptor.SupportedHttpMethods.Contains(HttpMethod.Head) ?
               parameter.BindWithAttribute(new FromUriAttribute()) : base.GetParameterBinding(parameter);   
}}
```

Then replacing then new default implementation in the config.services collection

```
 config.Services.Replace(typeof(IActionValueBinder), new CustomActionValueBinder());
```

Comment: It works only for specified types, but I'd like to apply [FromUriAttribute] to any request model

Comment: http://www.strathweb.com/2013/04/asp-net-web-api-parameter-binding-part-1-understanding-binding-from-uri/         The link in the comment describes what I believe would be the implementation of the behavior that you are looking for. There is an extension of the defaultactionvalueprovider followed by the instructions on replacing the default implementation with the custom implementation in the config.services collection.

Comment: @Bill it would be good if you update relevant part of the article in your answer and also include the link as reference in the answer.