# Blazor Post and Response C#

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

Having an issue posting from client to server in a server-side Blazor webapp.

I've created two simple classes in a shared library:

```
public class CommandRequest
{
    public int RequestNumber { get; set; }
}

public class CommandResponse
{
    public int ResponseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

My client side code:

```
@if (response == null)
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}
else
{
    <p>@response.ResponseNumber</p>
}

@functions {
    CommandResponse response;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        var request = new CommandRequest() {RequestNumber = 3};
        response = await Http.SendJsonAsync<CommandResponse>(HttpMethod.Post,"api/SampleData/ProcessRequest", request);
    }
}
```

My server side request handler:

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public CommandResponse ProcessRequest(CommandRequest request)
    {
        return new CommandResponse() { ResponseNumber = request.RequestNumber * 2 };
    }
```

When I debug this the ProcessRequest method is always passed an empty object, request.RequestNumber is 0. I'm new to ASP.NET and Blazor, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Adding [FromBody] attribute to the CommandRequest parameter solved my problem:

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public CommandResponse ProcessRequest([FromBody] CommandRequest request)
    {
        return new CommandResponse() { ResponseNumber = request.RequestNumber * 2 };
    }
```

A reference here:
[What is the function of [FromBody] Attribute in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175213/what-is-the-function-of-frombody-attribute-in-c)

Comment: Yeah, this gets me every time! :)