# Posting complex type in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I am experiencing an issue while developing a restful webapi with .Net Core, I can't consume a HTTP POST method that inserts a complex type object without specifying the parameter as "FromBody". Accordingly to the documentation from Microsoft...

[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

When using complex types on a HTTP POST I don't have to specify a `[FromBody]` data annotation, it should just work, but when I try to consume the method from the webapi...

```
// POST api/checker/
[HttpPost]
public int Insert(Entity e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Entity: {e.ID} - {e.Name}");
}
```

where entity has an id and a name, with this client method ...

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity);        
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();            
HttpResponseMessage message         = await client.PostAsync(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/checker", 
        new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

The object reaches the webapi with the values 0 `(ID)` and null `(name)`, unless when the webapi method signature uses the `[FromBody]` annotation. Am I missing something here? I've already done a research and couldn't figure this out.

**Update:**

This is my entity class:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is the serialized json using Newtonsoft's JSON.NET:

```
{"ID":99,"IsDeleted":false,"Name":"TestChecker"}
```

This is the output from the insert web api method:

```
Entity: 0
```

Comment: So you know that `[FromBody]` fixes this, why the relucantance to use that attribute on your parameter?

Comment: Please provide us json and class entity 
and also try to correct your url in the class method

Comment: @Jamiec, because if there is something conceptually wrong or I am missing something, I would like to learn about it, since in the official docs they explicitely say that the annotation is not necessary

Comment: @Esperadoce, I've edited the question to provide the additional information :)

Comment: @Jamiec, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24629106), by default [...] for complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body ... So I assume I am doing something wrong

Comment: The first of all, link you using is for old WebApi not for Core, and I'm not sure if the same rules will apply for Core. The easiest way to test that theory is to send Post request via Postman and see what will happen.

Comment: That's the link you should read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding (In your case, MVC and WebApi is the same in Core)

Comment: I didn't noticed that I was reading the wrong documentation, thanks a lot @LukaszMakowej! I've read it and it's not clear about whether should I specify the annotation or not, since it mentions a default behaviour, but surely makes a lot more sense than the other one on understanding the binding! :)

Comment: 1. You don't have to specify the annotation - I'm sure of it because It's working for me, but I'm using WebApi + Angular...

2. I suppose a problem in your case is with HttpClient - probably you not sending proper 'ContentType' header, which is used by Core Model Binder to determine which formatter to use. So as I said test it with Postman or try to add a proper ContentType header to your request or try to use WebClient instead?

Comment: Just a quick addition to the already provided answers, extracted from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#frombody-inference-notes), when using ApiControllerAttribute: ```The [ApiController] attribute applies inference rules for the default data sources of action parameters [...] [FromBody] is inferred for complex type parameters.```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a split/change in asp.net core from previous versions as MVC & Web Api Controllers merged together.

The default behavior in asp.net core, for POST requests, it that it will look for the data in request body using form data (x-www-form-urlencoded). You have to be explicit if you want to find appliction/json from body json.

This link might help you with details:
https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Thanks! Your answer plus [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) provided by @LukaszMakowej clarifies everything!

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that you need FromBody in .Net Core. See
[Create a Web API with ASP.NET Core...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc) 
See also : [Model Binding.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: Thanks Richard! This is also very helpful, I took a look over the Create method :)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using action `Insert` but when you call your api the url is "http://localhost:5000/api/checker" try again with this url "http://localhost:5000/api/checker/insert"? Maybe it will work and you don't need `[FromBody]`.

Comment: I've tried consuming using the insert suffix on the uri, but I get an 404 - Not Found error, the application routing is configured so I can make a call based on the HTTP (something like the present in the table from 
[this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api), where a post can be called by a "api/products" route)