# Call Api Controller PostAsJsonAsync simple type parameter

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, complextype

I am calling a MVC Api Controller using `PostAsJsonAsync`.

If I want to pass a Complex type like a Class instance, it Works fine. But I need to pass a Simple type as `string`, or `int` like

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await
 client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:62536/api/Controller/Method", "HELLO");
```

Got an error `404 Method` not found.

My WebApiController looks like this

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

My Api Controller Method looks like this.

```
public void Method(string id){}
```

If a try another Mehtod with `Int` type it does not work either..

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await
     client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:62536/api/Controller/MethodA", 123);

public void MethodA(int id){}
```

If I assign that value to a Complex Type like a Class.. it Works fine.

PostAsJsonAsync only Works for complex Type? How can it make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we have to specify FromBody and FromUri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625303/why-do-we-have-to-specify-frombody-and-fromuri)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void Method([FromBody] string id){}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like parse issue. Create string variable first then pass to method.

```
string x = (string)value;
```

Comment: "http:localhost:8080,

Comment: Http://localhost:8080

Comment: ([FromBody] string Id

Comment: Try [FromBody] for string or int