# Passing parameters to ajax to call action .net core 2 don't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I try to passing a parameter to simply action that return a partial view in a popup, but I can't to passing the parameters, and as if it did not arrive at the action.

I don't understand why???

I use .net core 2.

this my code.

The action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Detail([FromBody] string tableName, [FromBody] string code)
{
    var row = tableBLL.GetAllByCode(tableName, code);
    return PartialView("~/Views/Table/Detail.cshtml");
}
```

The jquery function. The value patamenter are hard coded to try the operation, after I should recover them from the table

```
 $("#dt_basic a.details").click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "/Table/Detail",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            "tableName": "IN_COMAGREE",
                            "code": "1"
                        }),
                        //data: '{code: "' + codeId + '" }',
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        //dataType: "html",
                        success: function (response) {
                            $('#dialog').html(response);
                            $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

The Partial view ( very simple in this moment )

```
 <form asp-action="" class="smart-form">
        <header>
            Name table
        </header>

        <fieldset>
            <section>
                <label class="label">Cod</label>
                <label class="input">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xs">
                </label>
            </section>

            <section>
                <label class="label">Descr</label>
                <label class="input">
                    <input type="text" class="input-xs">
                </label>
            </section>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Point of the call to the function

```
<table id="dt_basic" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                        }
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                            {
                                <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                            }
                                <td>

                                    <a href="#" class="details"> Edit @row[0]</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn bg-color-red txt-color-white btn-xs"> Delete @row[0]</a>
                                </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify(`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we have to specify FromBody and FromUri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625303/why-do-we-have-to-specify-frombody-and-fromuri)

Comment: You can only have one `[FromBody]` so use a custom class, see here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41027149/2181514

Comment: thanks for reply... I try to remove FromBoby and JSON.stringify( but don't work.. :-((((

Comment: I don't use a webservice my is a  action in a controller

Comment: The principle is the same.  You can only have one `[FromBody]` so you need to create a model with the two strings as properties.

Comment: Try this:  Change your action signature to `public IActionResult Detail([FromBody] string tableName) {`  (ie remove the other string) and add the `JSON.stringify(` back in to see what you get - you should get `tableName` as a json string.

Comment: public IActionResult Detail([FromBody] string tableName) 
        { result partialview (... ) }

and my Ajax : $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "/Table/Detail",
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            
                            "tableName": "IN_COMAGREE"
                            
                        }),

Don't work .. it' unbelievable

Comment: What do you get in the `error:` callback?

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint on the MVC action and running debug mode?

Comment: yes I Run in debugn mode and I put a break point in action and the parameter is null ... I don't obtain no error in call back but only that no value to parameter arrive.  have You try my code?

Comment: And your click handler is being called?  `$("#dt_basic a.details").click(function() { alert("click"); });`   (ie is the `details` anchor added dynamically?)

Comment: [_italic_] detail [_italic_] not is added dynamicaly is in layout... Is when i click on [_italic_] detail [_italic_] i view the alert

Comment: @freedomn-m can you do a example how this should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#binding-formatted-data-from-the-request-body) stated that,

> There can be at most one parameter per action decorated with `[FromBody]`. The ASP.NET Core MVC run-time delegates the responsibility of reading the request stream to the formatter. Once the request stream is read for a parameter, it's generally not possible to read the request stream again for binding other `[FromBody]` parameters.

You need to create a model

```
public class TableData
{
    public string tableName { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your action method use it like this

```
public IActionResult Detail([FromBody] TableData table)
```