# Passing exact parameters to Web API in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have written a Web API in ASP.NET Core, for which I need to pass 2 parameters; of them one is a string with grade, the other is of type list of studentInfo as shown here:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UpdateActiveStudents")]
public Response UpdateActiveStudents(string grade, [FromBody] List<StudentsInfo> lststudents)
{
        try
        {
            // My Logic
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            resp.flag = false;
            resp.message = ex.Message;
        }

        return resp;
}
```

To test this API, I used ARC (Advanced Rest Client). I passed the data as like this in a `POST` request:

```
{
    "grade": "B",
    "lststudents": [
                       { "StudentName": "abcdef", "RollNo": "user1"}, 
                       { "StudentName": "abcdef", "RollNo": "user1"}
                   ]
}
```

It throws a HTTP 400 status error with the following message :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SchoolHub.Model.StudentList]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'lststudents', line 2, position 13.

I'm unaware of this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this issue because you are not sending the data in the format at which ASP.Net Web API expects. ASP.net Web API needs some special format when dealing with a value like string and value type (int, bool, etc) parameter are marked with `FromBody` attribute.

Just remove `FromBody` it will work. For better understanding go with this link.

[Why do we have to specify FromBody and FromUri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625303/why-do-we-have-to-specify-frombody-and-fromuri)

Answer (score 0):

In Web API, general parameter binding rules for POST method are as follows -

```
Query string -> Primitive type
Request body -> Complex type
```

Now if you want to use POST method with Mixed parameters i.e in your case you are passing primitive (string) and complex (List), Web API will get the *grade* parameter from *query string* and *student* parameter from the *request body*.

Possible solutions to try -

1. In the ARC request it seems you are passing grade in request body instead of as a query string parameter. Try passing grade as a query string parameter.
2. Also add a class viz. `StudentInfoRequest` to wrap `List<StudentsInfo> lststudents` and then use `StudentInfoRequest` object to pass as parameter to `UpdateActiveStudents` method.
3. You dont need to mention [FromBody] in `UpdateActiveStudents` method as by default complex parameters are read from the request body by Web API.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You must add `[ApiController]` in the controller level. Code is as follows

```
[ApiController]

[Route("[controller]")]

public class studentController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdateActiveStudents")]
    public Response UpdateActiveStudents(string grade, List<StudentsInfo> 
                    lststudents)
    {
        //code
    }  
}
```