# Web API [FromBody] string parameter always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I've been trying to pass string data using `[FromBody]` but it is always null.

[image]

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, [FromBody] string value)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as `code-formatted text`, not screenshot. Would be nice if the request is posted in text form as well

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET Core you cannot simply use Model binding to get the whole JSON body text as string. You have to either create a [binding model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0#frombody-attribute) or read the request body manually:

```cs
var bodyText = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Sorry but i'm using ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, [FromBody] string value)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Success");
}
```

The [HttpPost] attribute tells the routing engine to send any POST requests to that action method to the one method over the other. This is a type of overloading.[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625303/why-do-we-have-to-specify-frombody-and-fromuri)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like below;

```
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject("your value parameter value");
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("your url" + "?id=your ID");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authString);

                HttpResponseMessage Res = client.PostAsync("", content).Result;

                var jsonContent = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
              
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

above codes work in my app.