# C# method receives null from ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to get accostumed to how ajax works, so I'm just trying to send a string to a C# method (I also tried Json and other types before) but no matter what I change the method seems to always receive null/not receiving any value.

```
function select(jobId){
    console.log(jobId);
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("SelectJob", "Home")',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'userId': jobId }),
        success: function () {
            console.log("yes");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("no");
        }
    });
}
```

This is the ajax call I currently came up with.
While the C# method called is defined like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectJob([FromBody] string jsonData)
{
    return Json(new { success = true, message = jsonData });
}
```

However the content of jsonData is always null.

I tried modifying the type of data sent, expected and its origin as FromBody, FromForm and none. I also tried different urls but that's not the issue since the method is correctly called.

Comment: Off the top of my head so not making it an answer but I don't think you need the `JSON.Stringify` call - I think you just need to pass your object in `data`

Comment: I tried that as well but the result is the same

Comment: Ah ok I think I see it - in your controller action you're expecting jsondata to be string, but your request is passing `application/json` - you need these to match.

Comment: So I should tell it I'm passing a string value? How can I do that?

Comment: and if you're passing a json object I'm almost certain you'll also need to drop the stringify call

Comment: Try changing the binding in the controller to a class that has a `UserId` property that is a string.

Comment: do you want to pass string data or json data? If you want to pass a string you can change your content-type to `text/plain`

Comment: Any type, I'll be satisfied if the method receives any kind of data somehow. I tried what you said but I get a "415 Unsupported Media Type" error.

Comment: @P.Magnusson I've tried that too already and still doesn't receive anything

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71731177/web-api-frombody-string-parameter-always-null ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify you ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("SelectJob", "Home")',
     type: 'post',
     data: { jsonData: jobId },
     success: function () {
         console.log("yes");
     },
     error: function () {
         console.log("no");
     }
 });
```

Then remove `[FromBody]`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SelectJob( string jsonData)
{
    return Json(new { success = true, message = jsonData });
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Omg it works. I've tried hundreds of combinations. So the problem was that there was a dataType at all?
It's really unintuitive to have to send a Json but receive a string for it to work but I'll stick with it if it works

Comment: Hi@MattiaDemontis  It's about  removing `contentType: 'application/json',` and the parameter name should be the same with data, so that the value can be bind successfully.

Comment: I see, so in the json the keys correspond to the parameters' names of the method and their value is the content sent related to them